# Why aren't there multiple notifications? And how to enable?

Tags: notification, notify-osd

I noticed in Ubuntu 11.04 there are only two notifications allowed at once, one being for sound, etc... and the other for all applications. I am using [udev-notify](https://launchpad.net/udev-notify) and my computer likes to dump my webcam and whenever that happens, there are two popups just for it being disconnected and then two more for re-connecting it which takes forever to see since I have to wait for each to close.

Is there a way to enable multiple notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, there is not a way to enable [multiple notification bubbles](https://bugs.launchpad.net/notify-osd/+bug/332955/comments/1):

> JD, this is the intended behaviour. We queue application notifications,
>   so that only one will be displayed at any time. That means they are
>   delivered asynchronously, which drives a number of the changes in our
>   implementation from other implementations.
>
> <sup>- [Mark Shuttleworth](https://launchpad.net/~sabdfl)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve 2 notification at once at a screen with `notify-send`. One is synchronous and another is asynchronous.

```
notify-send "Message1" -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything
notify-send "Message2"
```

Here for first command you don't need to wait for it to complete and it's output position is at top (checked in 12.04). You can replace that message at anytime.
To replace first command use:

```
notify-send "Message1replaced" -h string:x-canonical-private-synchronous:anything
```