# Multiple notifications via notify-osd or alternatives

Tags: unity, notification, notify-osd

I am searching for a way to display multiple notifications at once. The default app for Ubuntu seems to be `notify-osd`.

Can this be configured to display multiple notifications?

[PNotify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) is a very cool project bringing this feature in HTML world. But is there any way to do something like this, natively?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS: `notify-send`

```
$ urg=(low normal critical) ; for v in 0 1 2  ;do notify-send --expire-time=100 -u ${urg[$v]} "Mama says" "Mama had a little lamb - $v - ${urg[$v]}" ;done
```

... seems to bring up them one at a time, with order slightly re-arranged by `-u ${urg[$v]}`

---

Note:
https://askubuntu.com/a/51440/289138

Comment: Doesn't show me any notifications...

Comment: Posting edited.

Comment: Actually `notify-send` doesn't do anything on my machine (no error, just nothing).

Comment: That is strange, do you actually have `notify-osd` installed? `dpkg --list | grep notify` should show it. For me it also shows others: gir1.2-notify-0.7
libnotify-bin
libnotify4:amd64
notify-osd
notify-osd-icons
python-notify
python-pyinotify

Comment: I know it should work. I have `notify-osd` installed and the other notifications (from Rhythmbox for example) work.

Comment: `notify-osd` works again. The notifications are swill shown one by one... Aren't there other alternatives for notify osd that will show multiple notifications *same time*?